# Mac enter key issues on Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am using a Windows/Linux compatible keyboard on a MacBook Pro. It does not correctly send the MacOS keycode for the Enter key. This seems to be fine for all apps apart from Google Chrome. When I try and enter an address in the address bar and then hit the Enter key, it is ignored, presumably because the Windows/Linux keycode for the Enter key is sent. It appears that for MacOS, Google Chrome is expecting the MacOS keycode to be sent. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Quick Test - get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store & test the key. Enter is 0x4c, Return is 0x24

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work around that worked for me:

1. Export Bookmarks (open bookmark manager, select export from the menu in the upper right)
2. Remove Profiles
3. Restart
4. Re Install LastPass or other password manager
5. Reload Bookmarks (open bookmark manager, select export from the menu in the upper right)
6. Re-login into Google with Chrome
7. Don't select "Merge"